# How to read specific number of characters from a file in c++?

Tags: c++

if we have a file that stores the date and consequently followed by 24 numbers, what we need to do is to calculate the average of these numbers and put the output in another file. Also these numbers in the file are in char form and not int. I am unable to figure out how to read each number and add it. 
say the file consists of 10 such lines.
then the output file must have 10 lines of dates followed by the average value.

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream objtread,objtwrite;
    objtread.open("temperature.txt",ios::in);
    objtwrite.open("average.txt",ios::out);
    char temp[10];
    float temperature;


    while(objtread)
    {   float sum=0.0;

        objtwrite<<getline(temp,10);
        while()
        sum = sum + get(temperature);
        objtwrite<<setprecision(3)<<sum;

    }


}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the data/numbers file?

Comment: there are more than 5 numbers after the date, do you want to do the average of the 5 first or on all ?

Comment: all numbers, i used 5 just as an example

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: @JanviSharma I put a proposal of solution more an execution using your values, read my answer

Comment: `float temperature` – I'd rather prefer an unsigned value (int32_t, possibly int64_t, if you fear sum might get too big). You'd read in two steps then: integral, skipping the dot, then decimal. Final result: `value = integral * 100 + (integral >= 0 - integral < 0) * decimals`. You cannot run into rounding issues this way (apart from the final division by count, of course...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code cannot compile, for instance `while()` is invalid and *get()* is not defined

> calculate the average of these numbers and put the output in another file

currently you only compute the sum, you missed to divide to have the average

> the output file must have 10 lines of dates followed by the average value.

you missed to write the date

---

A simple way is to read the input file line per line then extract the date and after the values one per one using a *stringstream*

A proposal from your code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  fstream objtread,objtwrite;

  objtread.open("temperature.txt",ios::in);
  objtwrite.open("average.txt",ios::out);

  if (!objtread.is_open())
    cerr << "cannot open temperature.txt" << endl;
  else if (!objtwrite.is_open())
    cerr << "cannot open average.txt" << endl;
  else {
    string line;

    while (line.clear(), getline(objtread, line), line.length() > 10) {
      string date = line.substr(0, 10);
      stringstream ss(line.substr(10));
      double sum = 0, value;
      int n = 0;

      while (ss >> value) {
        sum += value;
        n += 1;
      }

      objtwrite << date << ' ' << setprecision(3) << ((n == 0) ? 0.0 : sum/n) << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall a.cc
/tmp % cat temperature.txt 
2019/02/28 20.44 20.25 20.14 20.02 19.87 19.66 19.41 19.13 19.51 20.44 21.82 22.92 23.49 23.60 22.72 22.54 22.28 21.62 20.34 19.05 20.39 19.72 19.11 19.12
2019/03/01 19.12 19.12 19.12 19.00 19.04 19.14 19.55 19.77 20.06 20.16 20.77 21.03 21.09 21.53 21.44 21.15 20.79 20.26 19.76 19.43 20.55 20.39 20.26 20.21
2019/03/02 20.13 19.91 19.63 19.68 19.81 20.07 20.41 20.16 20.99 21.91 22.47 23.36 23.26 23.27 23.20 23.20 22.80 21.95 21.34 21.18 21.07 21.16 21.15 21.14
2019/03/03 21.07 20.97 20.92 20.95 20.97 20.98 20.98 21.15 21.45 22.00 22.37 23.28 23.31 23.05 23.18 23.06 22.94 22.66 21.64 20.67 21.00 20.47 20.07 19.75
2019/03/04 19.41 19.02 18.76 19.16 18.99 18.90 18.80 18.86 19.50 20.57 20.87 21.00 21.94 22.81 23.11 23.10 22.01 22.32 21.84 21.63 21.52 21.57 21.60 21.61
2019/03/05 21.57 21.49 21.44 21.37 21.34 21.44 21.53 21.85 22.54 23.08 23.49 23.54 23.67 24.30 24.39 25.75 24.11 23.82 23.27 22.83 21.78 21.79 21.79 21.76
2019/03/06 21.72 21.72 21.75 21.93 22.09 22.11 21.68 21.09 21.62 21.81 22.35 22.25 22.72 23.34 23.21 23.49 23.19 22.73 22.43 22.01 18.50 17.11 16.95 16.70
2019/03/07 16.62 16.48 16.44 16.43 16.53 16.87 17.23 17.71 18.15 18.47 19.02 19.39 19.62 19.86 19.96 19.66 19.25 18.82 18.36 17.97 16.84 17.00 17.17 17.22
2019/03/08 17.17 16.78 16.29 15.73 15.38 15.38 15.53 15.78 16.15 16.66 17.29 17.95 18.38 18.63 18.83 18.96 19.05 19.08 19.10 19.14 18.36 18.63 18.89 19.14
2019/03/09 19.34 19.56 19.76 19.91 20.04 20.19 20.30 20.42 20.69 21.06 21.72 22.17 22.61 23.37 23.66 23.44 23.31 23.07 22.76 22.41 16.59 16.72 16.81 16.87
2019/03/10 16.86 16.88 16.85 16.70 16.58 16.45 16.31 16.10 16.20 16.44 16.75 17.07 17.21 17.19 17.27 17.05 16.84 16.75 16.69 16.59 16.53 16.43 16.14 15.98
2019/03/11 16.07 16.17 16.31 16.42 16.46 16.48 16.47 16.54 17.30 18.37 19.64 20.53 21.11 21.42 21.50 21.35 20.68 20.37 19.87 19.50 17.63 17.39 17.25 17.79
2019/03/12 18.37 18.61 18.39 17.70 17.40 17.99 17.14 17.20 19.31 20.27 20.94 21.80 22.30 22.54 22.58 22.45 22.15 21.42 20.37 19.32 19.61 19.29 19.01 18.79
2019/03/13 18.56 18.36 18.23 18.14 18.11 18.04 17.89 18.32 20.07 22.39 23.13 23.71 23.98 23.96 23.89 23.67 23.38 22.94 22.08 21.66 21.53 21.46 21.37 21.24
/tmp % ./a.out
/tmp % cat average.txt
2019/02/28 20.7
2019/03/01 20.1
2019/03/02 21.4
2019/03/03 21.6
2019/03/04 20.8
2019/03/05 22.7
2019/03/06 21.4
2019/03/07 18
2019/03/08 17.6
2019/03/09 20.7
2019/03/10 16.7
2019/03/11 18.4
2019/03/12 19.8
2019/03/13 21.1
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach would be to store each number in a `std::vector` and then use `std::accumulate` divided by the size of that vector `vector::size()` to get your average.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream obj_read("in.txt");

    if( !obj_read.is_open() )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(obj_read, line))
    {
        std::cout<< line << " = ";

        line.erase(line.begin(),line.begin()+line.find(" ")+1);

        std::stringstream s(line);
        std::vector<double> numbers;
        double v=0.0;

        while (s >> v)
            numbers.push_back(v);

        auto average = std::accumulate(std::begin(numbers),std::end(numbers),0.0) / numbers.size();
        std::cout<< average <<std::endl;
    }

    obj_read.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result is:

```
2019/02/28 20.44 20.25 20.14 20.02 19.87 19.66 19.41 19.13 19.51 20.44 21.82 22.92 23.49 23.60 22.72 22.54 22.28 21.62 20.34 19.05 20.39 19.72 19.11 19.12 = 20.7329
2019/03/01 19.12 19.12 19.12 19.00 19.04 19.14 19.55 19.77 20.06 20.16 20.77 21.03 21.09 21.53 21.44 21.15 20.79 20.26 19.76 19.43 20.55 20.39 20.26 20.21 = 20.1142
2019/03/02 20.13 19.91 19.63 19.68 19.81 20.07 20.41 20.16 20.99 21.91 22.47 23.36 23.26 23.27 23.20 23.20 22.80 21.95 21.34 21.18 21.07 21.16 21.15 21.14 = 21.3854
2019/03/03 21.07 20.97 20.92 20.95 20.97 20.98 20.98 21.15 21.45 22.00 22.37 23.28 23.31 23.05 23.18 23.06 22.94 22.66 21.64 20.67 21.00 20.47 20.07 19.75 = 21.6204
2019/03/04 19.41 19.02 18.76 19.16 18.99 18.90 18.80 18.86 19.50 20.57 20.87 21.00 21.94 22.81 23.11 23.10 22.01 22.32 21.84 21.63 21.52 21.57 21.60 21.61 = 20.7875
2019/03/05 21.57 21.49 21.44 21.37 21.34 21.44 21.53 21.85 22.54 23.08 23.49 23.54 23.67 24.30 24.39 25.75 24.11 23.82 23.27 22.83 21.78 21.79 21.79 21.76 = 22.6642
2019/03/06 21.72 21.72 21.75 21.93 22.09 22.11 21.68 21.09 21.62 21.81 22.35 22.25 22.72 23.34 23.21 23.49 23.19 22.73 22.43 22.01 18.50 17.11 16.95 16.70 = 21.4375
2019/03/07 16.62 16.48 16.44 16.43 16.53 16.87 17.23 17.71 18.15 18.47 19.02 19.39 19.62 19.86 19.96 19.66 19.25 18.82 18.36 17.97 16.84 17.00 17.17 17.22 = 17.9613
2019/03/08 17.17 16.78 16.29 15.73 15.38 15.38 15.53 15.78 16.15 16.66 17.29 17.95 18.38 18.63 18.83 18.96 19.05 19.08 19.10 19.14 18.36 18.63 18.89 19.14 = 17.595
2019/03/09 19.34 19.56 19.76 19.91 20.04 20.19 20.30 20.42 20.69 21.06 21.72 22.17 22.61 23.37 23.66 23.44 23.31 23.07 22.76 22.41 16.59 16.72 16.81 16.87 = 20.6992
2019/03/10 16.86 16.88 16.85 16.70 16.58 16.45 16.31 16.10 16.20 16.44 16.75 17.07 17.21 17.19 17.27 17.05 16.84 16.75 16.69 16.59 16.53 16.43 16.14 15.98 = 16.6608
2019/03/11 16.07 16.17 16.31 16.42 16.46 16.48 16.47 16.54 17.30 18.37 19.64 20.53 21.11 21.42 21.50 21.35 20.68 20.37 19.87 19.50 17.63 17.39 17.25 17.79 = 18.4425
2019/03/12 18.37 18.61 18.39 17.70 17.40 17.99 17.14 17.20 19.31 20.27 20.94 21.80 22.30 22.54 22.58 22.45 22.15 21.42 20.37 19.32 19.61 19.29 19.01 18.79 = 19.7896
2019/03/13 18.56 18.36 18.23 18.14 18.11 18.04 17.89 18.32 20.07 22.39 23.13 23.71 23.98 23.96 23.89 23.67 23.38 22.94 22.08 21.66 21.53 21.46 21.37 21.24 = 21.0879
```